# Python extension module: linking two extension modules

Tags: python, c

I have two Python extension modules written in C.  Each module defines a type, using the standard way of defining new Python types in C:

```
// in foo.c:
//
struct Foo
{
  PyObject_HEAD;
  int x;
  int y;
  int z;
};

PyTypeObject FooType = {
  PyObject_HEAD_INIT,
  0,
  "Foo",
  sizeof(Foo),

  ... etc ...
};
```

Now, I have a second Python extension module (part of the same package), called `Bar` (created in `bar.c`), which makes use of `Foo` instances.  So, I created a common header file, where `struct Foo` would be defined, and I also declared:

```
extern PyTypeObject FooType;
```

The reason I did this is because I wanted to make the `FooType` symbol available to `bar.c` for the purpose of doing an important type check.  In `bar.c`, I want to be able to say:

```
void Foo_TypeCheck(PyObject* obj)
{
  return (PyTypeObject*) (PyObject_Type(obj)) == &FooType;
}
```

...so that I can confirm that a certain object used in `bar.c` is actually an instance of `FooType`.  I need to be able to privately access the internal data members inside a `Foo` instance, so I have to check if a PyObject is, in fact, an instance of `FooType`.

But...

Using a standard disutils workflow, I get linkage errors when I actually import the `Bar` module in Python.  Basically, I have two extension modules, `foo.c` and `bar.c`, and I build both modules (as part of the same package) with disutils.  I have a common header file, `foo.h`, which defines `struct Foo`, and forward declares `FooType`.  But when `bar.c` is compiled, I get a linker error complaining about an undefined symbol to `FooType`.  Of course, the reason for this is pretty clear: `bar.c` has access to the *header file* `foo.h`, but it does not actually link with the shared object file created by `foo.c`, and so it does not see the implementation of `FooType`.

My `setup.py` file is straightforward:

```
foo_module = Extension('mypackage.foo', sources = ['foo.c'])
bar_module = Extension('mypackage.bar', sources = ['bar.c'])
setup(name = 'blah', ext_modules = [foo_module, bar_module], packages = 'mypackage')
```

So, how can I write my `setup.py` file so that this linker error doesn't happen?

Comment: Why not just have `bar.c` import `mypackage.foo` via [the conventional mechanism](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/import.html)?